# Поиск файла и сортировка командой awk

Tags: linux, awk

Как найти файл, имя которого содержит не меньше 7 любых символов ?

Как при помощи команды awk осуществить переход на новую строку ?

Например :

```
find -name '???????' -exec ls -is {}\; " awk '{print $3 " " $1 " " $2)'
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы $3 $1 $2 выводились на новой строке, а не через пробел (" ").

Comment: в вопросе содержатся два абсолютно несвязанных друг с другом вопроса. разбейте, пожалуйста, вопрос на два вопроса. либо уточните, **что именно** и **каким образом** связывает у вас программы find и awk.

Comment: Я ищу файл, который содержит 7 символов, затем вывожу его i-node и размер, а потом фильтрую этот вывод таким образом, что сначала выводится имя файла, затем его индексный дескриптор и размер. Проблема состоит в том, что нужно имя, индексный дескриптор и размер вывести на новой строке, а не в одной.

Comment: 1. приведённая вами команда синтаксически не верна. 2. в предикате `-name` вы указываете искать **ровно** семь символов, а не «больше или равно семи».

Comment: Знаю, поэтому и спрашиваю как найти не менее 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> не меньше 7 любых символов

в предикате `-name` надо указать `'???????*'`

> сначала выводится имя файла, затем его индексный дескриптор и размер

лучше воспользоваться для этого программой *stat*, а не пытаться видоизменить вывод программы *ls*:

```
$ stat --printf="%n\n%i\n%s\n" файл
```

подробности см. в `$ man stat`.

---

итого:

```
$ find -name '???????*' -exec stat --printf="%n\n%i\n%s\n" '{}' \;
```

пример вывода:

```
./файл1234
65233
139
./файл123
65229
0
```

Comment: А не более 7 символов как указываются в -name ?

Comment: в `-name` — никак. если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы.

Comment: @aleshka-batman, уже можете не задавать. я написал обобщающий вопросо-ответ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/600410/178576