# найти файлы/каталоги по критерию «имя указанной длины»

Tags: shell, gnu

как с помощью программы *find* (из пакета [*gnu/findutils*](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/)) найти файлы, соответствующие критерию «такая-то длина имени»?

в частности:

- длина имени ровно *n* символов
- длина имени больше или равна *n* символов
- длина имени меньше или равна *n* символов (больше нуля, конечно)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> длина имени ровно *n* символов

для этого достаточно предиката `-name` с параметром `'???'`, где количество вопросов соответствует числу *n*. например, «ровно три символа»:

```
$ find -name '???'
```

> длина имени больше или равна *n* символов

здесь тоже достаточно предиката `-name`, только в конце шаблона надо указать `*`. например, «больше или равно трём символам»:

```
$ find -name '???*'
```

> длина имени меньше или равна *n* символов (больше нуля, конечно)

здесь уже не хватит возможностей предиката `-name` и используемых в нём шаблонов. потребуются предикаты `-regex` и `-regextype` (`-regextype` оказывает влияние на **последующие** предикаты `-regex`, поэтому должен быть использован **до** них). например, «от одного до трёх символов»:

```
$ find -regextype posix-basic -regex '.*/[^/]\{1,3\}'
```

- теоретически, `-regextype` можно было бы и не указывать — по умолчанию используется тип *emacs*, но, к сожалению, по какой-то причине квантификаторы длины (`{x}`, `{x,y}`) в этом случае не работают;
- почему регулярное выражение такое длинное? потому что в случае `-regex`, в отличие то `-name`, сравнение производится с **путём** к файлу/каталогу, а не только с его именем (т.е., с `./каталог/файл`, а не `файл`).

Comment: Вариант: `-name '?' -o -name '??' -o -name '???'`? Но лучше `find . -type f -name '????*' -prune -o -type f -print`

Comment: Чаще всего фильтрую через grep/sed:   find ./ -type f -printf "%f" | grep -oP "^.{3}$"